# How to deduce that $A E[X] \subsetneq E[X]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This proof of this assertion was left as an exercise in my lecture of Introduction to algebraic geometry course ( Lecture Name consequences of Hilbert Nullstellansatz) and I am not able to prove this. I have been following my lecture notes.

There was following corollory deduced  in the lecture. Corollary: Let K be a field and $A \in I(K[X]) $ and E|K be any field extension. If $A \neq K[X] $  then show that$A E[X] \neq E[X]$.

In the proof of this corollary,  lecturer said that it is trivial that  $A E[X] \subsetneq E[X]$ but I am not able to deduce it despite thinking a lot .

Kindly give some hints to deduce it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$K[X]$ is a [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain). If $A \neq K[X]$, $A$ is generated by a polynomial $p$ of degree $n \ge 1$. Therefore all the polynomials of $AE[X]$ have a degree greater or equal to $n$ and $A E[X] \neq E[X]$.